# ExtJS4 - form to filter a grid

Tags: extjs4

I would like to have a form with which I could filter the data displayed in a grid. Here's a sketch:

```
// form to be used for filtering  

first name: [Mark]
last name:  [    ]
age:        [ 13 ]—[ 19 ]

(Filter)    (Clear filters)


// grid to be filtered

| first name | last name | age |
+------------+-----------+-----+
| Mark       | Twain     | 17  |
```

I know of the [Grid filer example from the ExtJS website](http://extdirectspring.ralscha.ch/demo/extjs4/gridfilter.html), but it doesn't seem intuitive for the users. How can I use a separate form to enter criteria for filtering a grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature-cfg-filters) api. There are methods to manipulate filters.
Example code which adds filter to grid:

```
var filter = grid.filters.getFilter('company');
if (!filter) {
    filter = grid.filters.addFilter({
        active: true,
        type: 'string',
        dataIndex: 'company'
    });
}
filter.setValue('3m Co');
```